# How do I remove the date functions from the where clause for the query below?

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to find some records from my user table in my own timezone. Can someone help out please? This is the query I am using on my MySql DB:

```
select *
from user
where date(convert_tz(now(), '+00:00', '+05:30')) > date(convert_tz(start_date, '+00:00', '+05:30')) AND
      now() < end_date;
```

Comment: It is not good to use functions in where clause.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/

Answer (score -1):

Try using datestamp or timestamp as the datatype while you are declaring date. Using this might help your code fetch the date and time format that you are using in your computer.

Comment: This is a little terse, but I think if you expand this to explain why that's useful in avoiding function calls, this will be a perfectly good answer.